# What are START and END comments for in Android sample code?

Tags: android, comments

I'm pretty new to Android development. Recently I've noticed a lot of START and END comments surrounding functional blocks in Google's own sample code, [for example](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java):

```
    // [START configure_signin]
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic
    // profile. ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN.
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = 
        new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END configure_signin]
```

I've never seen this particular style of comment in other codebases I've worked on, and I can't find any documentation or style guide that mentions their usage in Android code.

Do they serve any functional purpose (e.g. are they for use by some testing or documentation framework), or are they purely for the benefit of the reader?

Comment: It might be for automatically pulling code snippets out for documentation purposes. They might have a macro in their documentation files that says something like "insert here the `configure_signin` code from `SigninActivity.java`". I considered going that route for the code sample for [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android). I elected not to, to avoid confusing developers looking at the full source files. However, those comments are not part of normal Android app development, regardless of why Google has them there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are only to clarify what is going in. Think of them as flags that let you know where in your program you are.